# Change dynamically color line chart

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report with ReportingServices, that have a LineChart.
So for one series of the chart I have write this expression for color a column of dataset.

```
=iif((Sum(Fields!ProductionActual.Value, "chartDataSet")-Sum(Fields!ProductionPlanned.Value, "chartDataSet"))>0,"LightGreen","Red")
```

But I see only one color "Red".

This is a query that I use for create a chart

```
DECLARE @TemporaryTable TABLE 
                        (
                        Workcenter NVARCHAR(100),
                        Time Numeric,
                        min datetime,
                        max datetime,
                        StopInMinutes Numeric,
                        WorkingTime NUmeric
                        )

-- Get PO start and end time and the linkupID
DECLARE @DATA_START AS DATETIME
DECLARE @DATA_END AS DATETIME
DECLARE @MACHINE AS NVARCHAR(100)

DECLARE @Date as DATETIME
DECLARE @DateEnd AS DATETIME
SET @Date = '2014-11-24'
SET @DateEnd ='2014-11-26'
DECLARE @ProductionLine AS NVARCHAR(100)
SET @ProductionLine = 'COMBINER001'



SET @DATA_START = @Date
SET @DATA_END =DATEADD(second,86399,@DateEnd) 
SET @MACHINE= @ProductionLine

--SE NELL ELENCO DELLE LINEE Ho inserito la PACKER DEVO 
--AVERE UNA DIVERSA QUERY

 BEGIN
        --QUERY VALIDA PER TUTTE LE MACCHINE - PACKER001
    SELECT 
            mc.equipment as equipment
          , CONVERT (DATE, mc.CreatedOn)  as Data
          ,  sum(mc.quantity) as Production
          , tc.PlannedProduction as ProductionPlanned
          , ABS((sum(mc.quantity) - tc.PlannedProduction)) as ProductionVSPlanned
    FROM 
        [SQLIMELTC\IMELTCPROD].[FlexNet].[dbo].AT_MACHINE_COUNTER mc LEFT JOIN
        iMELReporting.dbo.TC_PlannedProduction tc ON 
            mc.equipment = tc.Workcenter AND
            CONVERT (DATE, mc.CreatedOn) = CONVERT (DATE, TC.PlannedDate) -- don't know if you need the second CONVERT() function
    WHERE 
      mc.CounterType = 1 
      and mc.CreatedOn between @DATA_START and  @DATA_END 
      and tc.PlannedDate between @DATA_START and  @DATA_END 
                  and mc.equipment = @MACHINE 
      and mc.CreatedOn IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY CONVERT (DATE, mc.CreatedOn), mc.equipment, tc.PlannedProduction
END
```

This is the result of my chart.

[image]

I expected to have the second column "Red" like that and the fourth column "LightGreen". But I have see, that there is another error, because the gray column have a wrong value. They have "3310" with value, in realty they should have "1000" and "2310"

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).